# Java HTML Unit save Unexpected page

Tags: java, htmlunit

Am trying to access the servlet page using `htmlunit` which contains one image.
I need to save the image or need to save the servlet page into html page.

Now am using

```
(UnexpectedPage) webClient.getPage(new URL("https://www.xxxx.com/servlet/xxxSer")
WebResponse response = currentPage.getWebResponse();
response.getContentType();
```

After that I do not know what to do. Is there any  idea to do this job.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the text content of the `WebResponse` (you also don't need the `URL` object):

```
Page page = webClient.getPage("https://www.xxxx.com/servlet/xxxSer");
String content = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Regarding the image you should be more clear on how you're getting it. If it is an image that is referenced in an `IMG` tag then use an `HtmlPage` and an `HtmlImage`. If you're requesting the image directly probably you should use `page.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream()`

Comment: Thanks this code working but i trying to store the image with this code InputStream is = response.getContentAsStream();    try { OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/xx");  
try {  
           byte[] buffer = new byte[400000];  
           for (int n; (n = is.read(buffer)) != -1; )   
               os.write(buffer, 0, n);  
           System.out.println("chk");
       }
       finally { 
        os.close(); 
       is.close(); 
       }
 } catch(Exception ex){
  
 } image content is displaying only  'Thank you' is this code is right for saving the image. is there any other idea

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about saving images, I just know a little bit about HtmlUnit :) I answered the question because it was strictly related to HtmlUnit. If you are unsure on how to save an image probably you should look for a related question or post a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
HtmlPage htmlpage = webClient.getPage(new URL("https://www.xxxx.com/servlet/xxxSer"));
String htmlcode = htmlpage.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Best

Comment: If i use the above code mean following error coming            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage

Comment: Is webClient of type com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient?

Comment: Thanks this code working but i trying to store the image with this code InputStream is = response.getContentAsStream();    try { OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/xx");  
try {  
           byte[] buffer = new byte[400000];  
           for (int n; (n = is.read(buffer)) != -1; )   
               os.write(buffer, 0, n);  
           System.out.println("chk");
       }
       finally { 
        os.close(); 
       is.close(); 
       }
 } catch(Exception ex){
  
 } image content is displaying only  'Thank you' is this code is right for saving the image. is there any other idea

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HTML Unit is not able to cast incompleted HTML Pages (some unclosing tags, for example). So, I could solve this error using HTMLParser which is included in HTMLUnit's packages (I'm using 2.36.0v). HTMLParser completes and handles this kind of casting errors. HtmlPage works if you need to execute JS.

```
//Web client creation.
Page page = webClient.getPage(url);
HtmlPage tmpPage = HTMLParser.parseHtml(page.getWebResponse(), webClient.getCurrentWindow());
// use tmpPage here
```